# Chartjs with Nextjs - User input for plotting graph

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a user input to work for my chartjs graph in nextjs. The key issue I am having is that every time the dataset values change the whole graph redraws. This wouldn't be an issue, except for the fact that my graph has an image in the background which needs to reload, causing the graph to flash.

I think I am close, but I can't seem to get my Chart object to exist outside of the useEffect() hook. I essentially need to destroy it every time otherwise I get the error on reload:

```
Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused.
```

Here is my code, maybe you can help me out! I have simplified it for clarity. THe QMl value gets passed from the parent component.

```
import Chart, { Title } from "chart.js/auto";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

type ScatterPlotProps = {
  yValue;
};

type Coordinates = [
  {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  }
];

export const ScatterPlot = ({ QMl }: ScatterPlotProps) => {
  //const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const chartRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartRef && chartRef.current && chartRef.current.getContext) {
      const data1: Coordinates = [
        {
          x: 10,
          y: QMl,
        },
      ];

      const data2: Coordinates = [
        {
          x: 20,
          y: QMl,
        },
      ];

      const scatterChart = new Chart(chartRef.current, {
        type: "scatter",

        data: {
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Data1",
              data: data1,
              backgroundColor: "rgb(104, 202, 0)",
              borderColor: "rgb(104, 202, 0)",
            },
            {
              label: "Data2",
              data: data2,
              backgroundColor: "rgb(180, 180, 255)",
              borderColor: "rgb(180, 180, 255)",
            },
          ],
        },
      });
      // I can't render the chart in the first place without using this destroy command.. but then the object isn't available in the other useEffect hook?
      return () => {
        scatterChart.destroy();
      };
    }
  }, []);

  // HERE IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE
  useEffect(() => {
    scatterChart.data.datasets[0] = [
      {
        x: 10,
        y: QMl,
      },
    ];
  }, [QMl]);

  return <canvas ref={chartRef} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use chart.js with React, I'd recommend using the react-chartjs-2 plugin:

https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/scatter-chart